# How can I call promise in handler of that promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What,s mistake? I think this code must output 22, 23, 24,25 ... etc infinitely.

```
function find() {
  let numberPage = 22;
  getPromiseOpenPage(numberPage);

  function getPromiseOpenPage (numberPage) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
      resolve(numberPage);
    })
  }
  getPromiseOpenPage().then(
    function (res) {
      console.log(res);
      getPromiseOpenPage(res++);
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: getPromiseOpenPage runs exactly three times ... the argument in those three occasions is `22`, `undefined` and `NaN`

Comment: Hi @АлександрКнязев if any of the answers has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a recursive loop to handle all infinity promise results.

```
getPromiseOpenPage(res++);
```

You are not handling `.then` here (and no, the first `getPromiseOpenPage().then(` doesn't count, since it is a different call).

So the solution would be something like this:

```
handlePromise() {
  myPromise.then((res) => handlePromise()); // On Promise complete it will go back
                                            // to the handler.
}
handlePromise(); // Start handlePromise the first time.
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't run `getPromiseOpenPage()` as a `initial` function

here inside `test(numberPage)` you provide the initial value to iterate, it call's the `getPromiseOpenPage()` which will return a `success` state.

and you `console.log(res)` the response value, and `iterate` it by `1` and again call the `test(res)` by providing the new incremented value incremented by `1` which is `23`

.......repeating same process again and again......... infinite times

```
  const numberPage = 22;

  function getPromiseOpenPage(p) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(p);
    });
  }


 function test(p) {
  getPromiseOpenPage(p).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    res = res+1;
    test(res);
  })
}

test(numberPage);
```